# Set membership for non-frozen sets

Tags: python, set

I thought I understood the relationship between `set` and `frozenset` in Python, but something magic is happening with set membership (`set1 in set2`) and I don't see how it can work.

A `set` of `frozenset` works:

```
>>> s = set()
>>> s.add(frozenset(['hello', 'world']))
>>> frozenset(['hello', 'world']) in s
True
```

I can't add unhashable types, such as `list`, to my `set`, and I can't use the `in` operator with unhashable types either:

```
>>> s.add(['hello', 'world'])
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>> ['hello', 'world'] in s
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Likewise I can't add a `set` to my set:

```
>>> s.add({'hello', 'world'})
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

...but I can use `in` with a `set` to check whether the corresponding `frozenset` is a member:

```
>>> {'hello', 'world'} in s
True
```

...and it gives the right result:

```
>>> {'jello', 'world'} in s
False
```

Why is `set1 in set2` special? Is it really calculating the hash of my set before testing membership? Or is it falling back on brute force?

**Edit:** found it, the C implementation of `set.__contains__` knows how to call call `key = frozenset(key)` whenever `hash(key)` throws `TypeError` and `isinstance(key, set)`.

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6c7d67c/Objects/setobject.c#L1890-L1897

```
rv = set_contains_key(so, key);
if (rv < 0) {
    if (!PySet_Check(key) || !PyErr_ExceptionMatches(PyExc_TypeError))
        return -1;
    PyErr_Clear();
    tmpkey = make_new_set(&PyFrozenSet_Type, key);
    if (tmpkey == NULL)
        return -1;
    rv = set_contains_key(so, tmpkey);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the source code, the current implementation (3.7) of [`set_contains`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Objects/setobject.c#L1888-L1906) reveals that indeed set objects are converted to frozen sets when checking for membership in a set:

```c
static int
set_contains(PySetObject *so, PyObject *key)
{
    PyObject *tmpkey;
    int rv;

    rv = set_contains_key(so, key);
    if (rv < 0) {
        if (!PySet_Check(key) || !PyErr_ExceptionMatches(PyExc_TypeError))
            return -1;
        PyErr_Clear();
        tmpkey = make_new_set(&PyFrozenSet_Type, key);
        if (tmpkey == NULL)
            return -1;
        rv = set_contains_key(so, tmpkey);
        Py_DECREF(tmpkey);
    }
    return rv;
}
```

Basically, if the given object is a set (`PySet_Check(key)`), then a new frozen set is created (`make_new_set(&PyFrozenSet_Type, key)`) and membership is checked again (`set_contains_key(so, tmpkey)`). I do not think this is actually documented anywhere, and it is probably meant to be a feature that "just works" without you even noticing if you do not think too hard about it.

It does seem to be something in the same spirit as the rejected [PEP-0351](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0351/), although it is not based on any special method and it is specific to sets only.

EDIT: For more details, this feature was apparently first implemented back in 2003 ([commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/19c2d77842290af9b5f470c1eea2a71d1f77c9fe)) by [Raymond Hettinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1001643/) at the request of [Alex Martelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95810). So if one of them happens to be around maybe they could give more background on this.

EDIT 2: Worth noting, this can have a significant performance impact under particular circumstances:

```
s = set(range(100000))
sf = frozenset(s)
t = { sf }
%timeit sf in t  # True
>>> 31.6 ns ± 1.04 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
%timeit s in t  # True
>>> 4.9 ms ± 168 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

The test is *five* orders of magnitude slower in the second case!

EDIT 3: I [raised an issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue34719) for the Python team to discuss the possibility of deprecating this behavior, since it seems inconsistent and potentially problematic. The developer considered it was still a useful feature and the cons were not worth breaking compatibility.

Comment: Good find, I was peaking at the source myself, interesting that they decided to implement this at all really rather than raise a `TypeError`; I can't imagine it's a common use case